# Are these pea plants sun damaged?

Tags: diagnosis, peas

I transplanted a few sugar snap peas into my raised bed a week or two ago and noticed that some of the leaves were turning white. The whiteness starts at the base of the leaf and radiates out from there.

I didn't give much time for the plants to harden because once the shoots started coming up they started growing really fast (I started them in a seeding tray and their cells looked a bit small for them). I suspect it might be sun damage from that but I'm not sure since I can't seem to find any images that match what I'm getting so I'm wondering if someone could confirm. If it is, should new growth be okay?

[image: Pea plant]

Comment: Transplanted peas? Peas are among the hardiest of plants, in the "no kidding, plant as soon as ground can be worked" sense...

Comment: Weather's been pretty cool in Toronto this year and would drop below freezing pretty much everyday until maybe three weeks ago. Is that something that'd be okay with hardier plants?

Comment: Mine have been out through several major freezes, no harm done, happily germinating in place. They are tough. Hopefully yours will bounce back. Spinach, carrots, lettuce are all pretty immune to early-season frost and freeze, as well, when direct planted. Garlic laughs.

Comment: @Jon, yes peas can survive frosts in Michigan pretty easily. Even frosts several days in a row as long as daytime temps thaw them out. I'm not convinced it's sun damage. Maybe too much fertilizer too soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitening of leaves is usually to do with cold, not sun - if you started these inside or under cover, then didn't harden off properly, that'll explain what's happened. The newer leaves in the picture don't seem to be affected, so hopefully, the plant will grow on well.